Is it possible to set up a external button that will run a excel macro?
I have created a timer that is supposed to track a manufacting takt time and i have it currently set up to reset after i click a button in the excel. I have done some research but unable to find anything on using outside inputs for macros. is it possible?
have currently just done research on the topic and found very little. Program is running as intended - the external button

Outside inputs... as in not opening Excel?  So your user would click a button on some user interface and it would run the Excel macro?  If this is the case, I would suggest that your external interface button should simply log the action in a file, then when your Excel file is opened, the macro can read in all of the entries (button presses) and make the calculations.

Needs more info on exactly what "using outside inputs for macros" means in this context.

Sorry for the miscommunication.  The excel would be open and be displayed on a tv screen. My timer is counting down from a set time. Once a button is pushed it resets the timer to the originally set. I was curious to see if you could set up a physical button that is set up through hdmi port, usb port, or Bluetooth? The purpose of the project is to give a visual on time without having to get on a computer

How does that differ from clicking on a mouse button?

There are USB buttons you can get online (like this: https://www.amazon.com/Programmable-Decision-Keyboard-Customized-Combination/dp/B09CLBDYSS) that can be programmed to send in a keystroke or combination (like CTRL+SHFT+Y, for example). You could set your macro to be kicked off by that key combination. It's hokey and kludgy, but so is creating a UI/Display in Excel so it feels like a good fit.

Awesome, that would work great. Thank you all for the info and for bearing with me as I am a little slow

Maybe Chromecast/SmartView your mobile phone's timer app?
